# Send input events to second applications

Tags: qt, winapi, qt5, qapplication

I've a qt 5.5 application working on one part of a monitor displaying it's user interface. A different application does this for the rest of the screen. My question is: does a practical solution exists to display a transparent widget above the second  applications screen space to have complete input focus for the entire screen and forward all input actions relevant to second application? (which will be rendered always behind that widget).

The second application is not a qt but WinApi application. Is it possible to filter  input events (mouse, keyboard, etc) an send a subset to a different process in this constellation? Or when making this application a qt application?

Thank you!

Comment: I think that you should use predefined solutions: process injection and hooks.

Comment: A transparent window doesn't receive input, so no, that's not a practical solution.